# How would I hide a listbox widget when an entry widget isn't focused?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a tkinter app and am trying to only show a listbox when an entry widget (and, of course, the listbox itself) has not got the focus. In other words, it only shows search suggestions when you are in the entry widget/typing.

```py
    self.from_query.bind("<FocusIn>", self.updateList)
    self.from_query.bind("<FocusOut>", self.toggle)

    # Dynamically updates the query frames listboxes
    def updateList(self, *args):

        search_term = self.users_search.get()

        self.from_listbox = Listbox(root)
        self.from_listbox.place(x=100, y=652)
        self.from_listbox.pi = self.from_listbox.place_info()
        self.from_listbox.config(highlightbackground="red")

        test_lbox = ['Adam', 'Lucy', 'Barry', 'Bob', 'James', 'Frank', 'Susan', 'Amanda', 'Christie']

        self.from_listbox.delete(0, END)

        for item in test_lbox:
            if search_term.lower() in item.lower():
                self.from_listbox.insert(END, item)
    def toggle(self):
        print("clicked")
```

I have tried to create a toggle function that just prints "clicked" when the entry no longer has focus but it doesn't ever get to running that function

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `place_forget` method to remove placed widgets. If you want it to show, you'll have to call `place` again. 
Heres some info on the `place` and `place_forget` methods:
https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm

i.e.:

```
def toggle(self):
    if self.listbox_is_showing:
        self.listbox.place_forget()
        self.listbox_is_showing = False
    else:
        self.listbox.place(x=100, y=652)
        self.listbox_is_showing = True
```

you will have to set `listbox_is_showing` in `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `bind` and the event is triggered, the function always return an object describing the event. Your `toggle` method takes no args so it will raise a `TypeError`.

To have your method works, simply add `event=None` to your `toggle` function:

```
def toggle(self,event=None):
    print("clicked")
```